# If $\vec{x}$ spans a set of vectors, show that $\vec{x}$ also spans anoter set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following here:

> Suppose that $\mathbf{x}\in \text{Span}(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w},\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{u}).$ Show that $\mathbf{x}\in\text{Span}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}).$

All I could really do is show that:

$\mathbf{x}=a(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})+b(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w})+c(\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{u})$ for scalars $a,b,c$.

but how does this help me prove that $\mathbf{x}\in\text{Span}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})$?

I could rearrange the first equation but this still doesn't seem to show me anything...

Comment: Don't you believe that $(a+c)u+(a+b)v+(b+c)w$ is a linear combination of $u,v,w $?

Comment: Oh yeah right... I could just add the constants. I wonder why I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: Going the other way is the more "interesting" route. And characterising exactly what's special about $u+v, u+w, v+w$ that lets you do it is a pretty important theoretical exercise.